# What Happens if I Remove a DE *before* I Install Another?

Tags: apt, package-management, uninstall, kde, desktop-environments

I have a FS Amilo laptop with 2GB RAM and Lubuntu/Kubuntu (and Puppy Linux) installed. I'd like to remove Kubuntu and try Xubuntu. I was wondering, what would happen if I uninstall the Kubuntu DE before I add another? For instance, if I try to run

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo aptitude remove '?and(?and(?reverse-depends(kubuntu),?not(?reverse-depends(ubuntu-desktop))), ?not(?or(?priority(required), ?priority(important))))' ubuntu-desktop+
```

from Konsole terminal, would I get an error, or... ?
(The reason I'm asking is not only out of curiosity, there is a practical reason for it, too: I have limited space in my drive, so I'm not sure I have the extra space needed to add a new DE before removing Kubuntu).

Comment: Because of the special capabilities of the ext4 file system, you should be able to delete files that are currently in use, if you have enough (root) privileges. Therefore you should be able to upgrade or remove packages which are in use as well. I would recommend to perform it without an active GUI login from a TTY session though anyway, but I don't see any problems.

Comment: I can confirm the procedure worked as expected and the new DE seems to be also working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have no problem to run and finish the command. You'll also be able to work with KDE programs already opened further. But you should be prepared for problems.

For this reason, logging out of the KDE session and change to tty1: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

Login and run your deinstallation. `aptitude` runs `autoremove` per default automatically, but you should run

```
sudo aptitude autoclean
```

after the command in your question. Now install your new DE.

---

**Warning:** I havn't tested the command in your question.

Comment: The `apt*`-god is back! \o/